# actionbar sherlock - how to set background image for activity area in the theme

Tags: android, background, actionbarsherlock

I am using actionbar sherlock and it works very well. The only problem I have is to figure out how to set the background image for the area which is used by the activities. All I end up with is setting a background image for the actionbar itself.

Any suggestion highly appreciated

martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `windowBackground` attribute is perfect for this.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">here!</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thx a lot works very well - for my app i prefer AmJay's solution as with it the actionbar stays black yet that is just my personal preference

Comment: The action bar is transparent by default. If you want a black action bar you should switch to using the solid style. Setting the activity background on the window is much faster than just setting it on your layout. Ref: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/04/speed-up-your-android-ui/

Comment: great, thx a lot for the hint Jake. Is there a way to scale the image, like i can scale a ImageView with android:scaleType="centerCrop" for example

Comment: You would have to create an XML drawable which has a <bitmap> entry where you can control things like that. See examples at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Thanks a lot again and thanks for the great actionbar sherlock library (just realising who is answering me here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the background for your main layout in your activity.
Eg. in your layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/myImage" >
```

Comment: thx works very well - sorry beginner following up question, how do i specify the scaling for the image in a layout and how do i "tint" it - thx

Answer (score 0):

just write following line of code in your onCreate().

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_image);
```